# How to do user login authentication and user session in Angularjs?

Tags: java, angularjs, session, authentication

I am new to Angularjs and I am getting problem in hitting my login rest service which is written in Java. Please tell me how to send authentication headers and data to my service so that I can successfully login and maintain the session of the user too.

Comment: The first step would be to write some code.  You could even search the web for something like "angularjs authenication example"

Answer (score 0):

To get started, try [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Sample from documentation

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){ /* success */}, function(){ /* error */});
```

An yes, try to search something like [angular authentication example](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular%20authentication%20example)